# mendeley plugin on wordpress Failed retrieving OAuth2 access token:

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0, token, mendeley

I am trying to connect my mendeley to my wordpress account.

However, I keep getting this error:

> Failed retrieving OAuth2 access token: {"message":"Credentials are required to access this resource."}

Any advice/help?

Comment: You should post a [mcve] to make your problem easier to diagnose.

Comment: @Haem I'm not familiar with the coding aspect, basically, we are planning to launch a wordpress website, we want to use the mendeley plugin to showcase various papers on assistive technology. There is an instruction set that says :" The Mendeley API uses the OAuth2 protocol for doing this. When you press the button bellow, the plugin requests authorization from Mendeley. Therefore, you will be asked by Mendeley to log in and to authorize the request from the login. As a result an Access Token will be generated and stored in the plugin."

Comment: When i click on the said button it leads me to the mendeley where i log in and then the error above shows up